# how use GCP for machine learning

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I am thinking of doing some machine learning tasks using GCP $300 credits. I hope to use a kaggle data set for this matter. Could anyone tell me the option should I choose to use from the google cloud platform suite and any available tutorial resources for this matter.

Thanks

Michael

Comment: You don't really give us any idea of your machine learning background. It's a huge field. Are you familiar with the various ML libraries in python or java? Are you looking to do deep learning with neural nets? What sorts of problems are you trying to solve?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Yes I am using python to train a tabular dataset from kaggle website. Would I be able to transfer the data from kaggle without first downloading it to my computer.? Also how do I use gcp to do machine learning task on this data. Appriciate your help.

Comment: Maybe this ... https://medium.com/google-cloud/gcp-essentials-machine-learning-overview-bfeba5d800e7

Comment: You can browse coursera machine learning specialisation which are great. You can also search some [Qwiklabs](https://www.qwiklabs.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How use GCP for machine learning?

Actually there are a lot of different possible answers, depending on what type of ML training you would like to do with Google Cloud Services.

I highly recommend you to take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59467642/migrate-from-running-ml-training-and-testing-locally-to-google-cloud/59468948#59468948) in which you will see the basic structure that it is recommended for using ML in Google Cloud.

Also, you will find some tutorials that could help you get your firsts steps into doing Machine Learning on Google Cloud.

To sum up; Machine Learning in Google Cloud can be summarized in:

- Data Ingestion and Collection
- Storing the data.
- Processing data.
- ML training.
- ML deployment.

Each one of this processes can use their own Google Cloud's product, and it depends on the kind of use that you would like to do. You will find further information in the post above.

> Any available tutorial resources for this matter?

It also depends a lot in what kind of tutorials you are looking for. If you would like to have a deeper understanding on how to do Machine Learning in Google Cloud, I would go with Coursera.

Coursera have some really good courses that talk about ML. For example:

- [Machine Learning with TensorFlow on Google Cloud Platform Specialization](https://www.coursera.org/specializations/machine-learning-tensorflow-gcp).
- [Google Cloud Platform Big Data and Machine Learning Fundamentals](https://es.coursera.org/learn/gcp-big-data-ml-fundamentals)

As for Google Cloud's documentation it really depends on what products you would like to use, but you could take a look at:

- [Using scikit-learn on Kaggle and AI Platform Prediction](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/scikit/using-kaggle)

I hope it helps. As mentioned before, you will encounter a more fine and detail explanation in this [post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59467642/migrate-from-running-ml-training-and-testing-locally-to-google-cloud/59468948#59468948)